# How to connect screen/tmux/byobu to dbus?

Tags: dbus, byobu, gnu-screen

Sometimes in GUI I use `byobu` , but I get the following error  with `qdbus`

> Could not connect to D-Bus server:
>   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket
>   /tmp/dbus-1rnudRVZOD: Connection refused

and the following with `dbus-monitor`

> Failed to open connection to session bus: Failed to connect to socket
>   /tmp/dbus-1rnudRVZOD: Connection refused

How can I fix this ?

What I've tried so far is exporting couple variables in my `.bashrc`

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DISPLAY
```

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to monitor some specific dbus daemon instance, connected to particular process (like gnome-session or something like this). First find PID of that process

```
$ pidof gnome-session
34001
```

Then check its env vars for *DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS*

```
$ xargs --null --max-args=1 < /proc/34001/environ | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Now you can export extracted var

```
$ export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-p7YOEk,guid=ed5c03623a
```

Comment: To simplify that all into a one liner, it would be: `export $(xargs --null --max-args=1 < /proc/$(pidof gnome-session)/environ | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)`